# What values should be initially assigned to Checkpoints for a new Genesis block?

Tags: bitcoind, genesis-block, checkpoints

I have created a **new Genesis block**. What values should be assigned to these fields?

```
namespace Checkpoints
{
typedef std::map<int, uint256> MapCheckpoints;

struct CCheckpointData {
    const MapCheckpoints *mapCheckpoints;
    int64_t nTimeLastCheckpoint;
    int64_t nTransactionsLastCheckpoint;
    double fTransactionsPerDay;
};
```

The original Checkpoints assignment for main network can be found here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.10.2/src/chainparams.cpp#L55-L77

```
static Checkpoints::MapCheckpoints mapCheckpoints =
        boost::assign::map_list_of
        ( 11111, uint256S("0x0000000069e244f73d78e8fd29ba2fd2ed618bd6fa2ee92559f542fdb26e7c1d"))
        ( 33333, uint256S("0x000000002dd5588a74784eaa7ab0507a18ad16a236e7b1ce69f00d7ddfb5d0a6"))
        ( 74000, uint256S("0x0000000000573993a3c9e41ce34471c079dcf5f52a0e824a81e7f953b8661a20"))
        (105000, uint256S("0x00000000000291ce28027faea320c8d2b054b2e0fe44a773f3eefb151d6bdc97"))
        (134444, uint256S("0x00000000000005b12ffd4cd315cd34ffd4a594f430ac814c91184a0d42d2b0fe"))
        (168000, uint256S("0x000000000000099e61ea72015e79632f216fe6cb33d7899acb35b75c8303b763"))
        (193000, uint256S("0x000000000000059f452a5f7340de6682a977387c17010ff6e6c3bd83ca8b1317"))
        (210000, uint256S("0x000000000000048b95347e83192f69cf0366076336c639f9b7228e9ba171342e"))
        (216116, uint256S("0x00000000000001b4f4b433e81ee46494af945cf96014816a4e2370f11b23df4e"))
        (225430, uint256S("0x00000000000001c108384350f74090433e7fcf79a606b8e797f065b130575932"))
        (250000, uint256S("0x000000000000003887df1f29024b06fc2200b55f8af8f35453d7be294df2d214"))
        (279000, uint256S("0x0000000000000001ae8c72a0b0c301f67e3afca10e819efa9041e458e9bd7e40"))
        (295000, uint256S("0x00000000000000004d9b4ef50f0f9d686fd69db2e03af35a100370c64632a983"))
        ;
static const Checkpoints::CCheckpointData data = {
        &mapCheckpoints,
        1397080064, // * UNIX timestamp of last checkpoint block
        36544669,   // * total number of transactions between genesis and last checkpoint
                    //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
        60000.0     // * estimated number of transactions per day after checkpoint
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate several blocks and put (block_height, block_hash) pairs into the following field. Or just delete all of the checkingpoints : )

```
static Checkpoints::MapCheckpoints mapCheckpoints =
        boost::assign::map_list_of
        ( BLOCK_HEIGHT, uint256S("0xBLOCK_HASH"));


static const Checkpoints::CCheckpointData data = {
        &mapCheckpoints,
       bitcoin-cli getblock [last checkpoint block], then get the unix time, // * UNIX timestamp of last checkpoint block
        Write a script to count?,   // * total number of transactions between genesis and last checkpoint
                    //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
        estimate_a_number     // * estimated number of transactions per day after checkpoint
    };
```